# How to find 5 biggest value from php array with original keys?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

This array keys is a database primary keys and i need to find biggest value from array and after that update query which need this primary keys. so i need to it will be remain same keys.

> My array

```
Array ( [1] => 7 [2] => 2 [3] => 2 [4] => 10 [5] => 15  [6] => 11 [7] => 40 )
```

> i need this output

```
Array ( [7] => 40 [5] => 15 [6] => 11 [4] => 10 [1] => 7 )
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php - the rest is up to you

Comment: i try this but it finds only largest value and keys are change

Comment: https://eval.in/836445 this page gives me internal error.

Comment: Hmmm, eval's been having some issues, I'll move it to another sandbox and update my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP [arsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) function will sort your array in descending order and maintain the indices.

```
$array = array ( 1 => 7, 2 => 2, 3 => 2, 4 => 10, 5 => 15,  6 => 11, 7 => 40 );
arsort($array);
print_r($array);
```

Demo: <s>eval.in/836445</s>https://3v4l.org/KQB5Y

To limit it to the top five use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
print_r(array_slice($array, 0, 5, true));
```

https://3v4l.org/DSkRt